# Python+Celery: ignore task results on a per-invocation basis?

Tags: python, celery

Is it possible to ignore task results on a per-invocation basis?

For example, so I can ignore the results of tasks when they are being run during a web request, but wait for the result (which might have, eg, debug info) when I'm running the task interactively?

I know that Tasks have the `ignore_result` flag, but I'm wondering specifically if it's possible to set `ignore_result` on a per-invocation basis (not a "global" basis).

Answer (score 1):

Not normally, because ignore_result is a property of a Task that only the workers use (to decide whether to send a result back).

But you could do it if you used your own task parameter (avoid calling it ignore_result), and have the task set its ignore_result based on that:

```
task mytask(please_ignore_result):
    mytask.ignore_result = please_ignore_result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ignore_result=True/False` while calling `apply_async` or `delay`

```py
@app.task 
def hello():
    print('hello world')

# storing/rejecting results per invocation basis    
res = hello.apply_async(ignore_result=True)
res1 = hello.apply_async(ignore_result=False)
```

You might run into [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5398) error if you are running an older version of celery. You can read the docs about how to use `ignore_result` in more detail [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=ignore_result#ignore-results-you-don-t-want)